# Why the sigmoid is known as logit?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology, special-functions

The excerpt I took from one book, is telling me that sigmoid different name is logit.

[excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFKIU.png)

What is the reasoning behind? I don't get it.

I know the sigmoid function is defined:

$sigmoid(x) = \large \frac{exp(x)}{1+exp(x)} $

I know the logit function is defined as:

$logit(x) = \large \log \frac{x}{1-x}$

And I even know these two functions are inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **logi**s**t**ic function has its name from the property that it starts off exponentially (like unrestricted  population growth) and later grows slower until it asymptotically stops (as if due to resource exhaustion, i.e., "logistic" problems with "feeding" the population). The function $x\mapsto\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}$ matches this description well because for $x\ll 0$, this is $\approx e^x$ and for $x\gg0$ this is $\approx 1$. As this is also one of many functions whose graph is S-shaped, it is also called *sigmoid*.

However, **logit** is usually defined as $x\mapsto \ln \frac x{1-x}$.

Comment: so you are telling essentially that any S-shaped function may be called *sigmoid*?

Comment: Yes.  "Sigmoid" is a general description of S-shaped function.  It applies not only to $\exp(x)/(1+\exp(x))$, but also no many others, such as $\arctan(x)$.